# generate excel spredsheet with button

Tags: c#, excel, command

I would like to generate an excel spread sheet with c# that contain a button, and that I can handle the event when the user click on this button...

Any idea please...

Comment: You want the button in Excel spreadsheet or generate the spreadsheet with button or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c) thread. It may be helpful. There is a lot of references to excel libs.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much information to go on here, but my guess is that you need to do something similar to "[create a button with macro from code module programmatically](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=275)".

Basically, you will need to create the button and insert the vba linked to the button.

Also take note of the difference between a CommandButton and a FormsButton. The former already has an event attached to it. This is the same type of button as described in the link above. So if you create a button named called 'myVBAButton', the corresponding subroutine that it automatically linked to the click event would look like

```
Private Sub myVBAButton_Click() 

End Sub
```

Remember, you still need to add the above code from your the code that creates the button.